# Python: How do you write a function that counts the occurrences of a specified non-overlapping string s2 in another string s1?

Tags: python

For example, count("system error, syntax error", "error") returns 2.
I'm not sure how to write this code.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
I tried starting the code, but I got lost after this.

```
def main():
     s1 = input("Please enter string 1: ")
     s2 = input("Please enter string 2: ")
     print(count(s1,s2))
def count(s1, s2): # define function count that takes two strings as argument
     count = 0  # set initial count to 0

     while s2 < len(s1):

main()
```

Comment: @neepythonhelp, why don't directly use the builtin function count(). use s1.count(s2) .

Comment: I would like to learn how to do it using a counter rather than a built in function

Comment: Sorry I don't really get what you want to do. Do you want to increment the counter by one in every iteration in the while loop?

Comment: Yes, I'm just not sure how to write the code to find the occurrence. Sorry if it is unclear

Comment: [Here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h) is one way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go :

```
def count(s1, s2):    # define function count that takes two strings as argument
    counter = 0    # set initial count to 0
    for i in range(len(s1)) :    # iterate over every character
        if s1[ i  : i + len(s2) ] == s2 :    # if match .. 
            counter += 1    # .. increment the counter
    return counter
```

One-liner :

```
count = lambda s1, s2 : sum([ 1 for i in range(len(s1)) if s1[ i : i + len(s2) ] == s2 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

The more optimized code considering the statement ***"Non-overlapping string"***:

```
s1 = "This is the code th fwefthe"
s2 = "th"

i = 0
len_s1, len_s2 = len(s1), len(s2)

count = 0
while i < len_s1:
   if s1[i:i+len_s2] == s2:
     count += 1
     i += len_s2
   else:
     i += 1
```

you can see that when i get a match, the counter i is increased by len(s2) rather than incrementing by one. it does improve performance.

Comment: You can also increase the performance of the program by saving the lengths of `s1` and `s2` in variables, and use those in place of `len(string)`, since the value of those strings never change. This would save time because Python doesn't have to keep recalculating the length of each string over and over.

Comment: @algerbrex, thanks for the suggestion, edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's me but I think the problem is poorly written, you can find it @ [Intro to Programing python by Daniel Liang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTtp9.jpg)

here's my solution using Counter:

```
from collections import Counter


def main():
   s1 = input("Enter first string: ").strip()
   s2 = input("Enter second string: ").strip()
   count(s1, s2)


def count(s1, s2):
  first = s1.split()
  second = s2.split()

  allElements = first + second
  newList = Counter(allElements)

  for k, v in newList.most_common(1):
      print(v)


main()
```

if I test with count("system error, syntax error") it actually returns 2, couldn't make it work with the answer above. I mean the test has 3 arguments the the count function has 2 ?..Whaaa

Answer (score 0):

```
def twoStrings(s1, s2):
 s1 =sorted(s1)
 s2 = sorted(s2)
 i = 0
 j = 0
 result = 0
 while i < len(s1):
  while j < len(s2):
   if s1[i] == s2[j]:
    result = 1
    print ('YES')
    break
   else:
    j += 1
  j = 0
  if result == 1:
   break
  else:
   i += 1
 if result == 1: return "YES"
 else: return "NO"
```

Comment: It would be useful if your answer contained an explanation of why this works, rather than just showing code.